# How can I get 1000 sample from each class of dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get sample of each class, for example, 1000 rows each class 1, 2, 3, 4 or fewer if there aren't enough rows.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Date': ['2023-10-20', '2023-10-21', '2023-10-22', '2023-10-23', '2023-10-24' ...],
    'class': [4, 1, 1, 2, 3 ...],
    'other_col1': [5, 6, 3, 1, 4 ...],
    'other_col2': [15, 10, 72, 6, 8 ...]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I try simple approach but want more sophisticated way

```
sampled_data = []

for class_label, group in df.groupby('class'):
    if len(group) >= sample_size:
        sampled_data.append(group.sample(sample_size))
    else:
        sampled_data.append(group)

sampled_df = pd.concat(sampled_data)
```

Comment: Just `df.groupby('class').sample(n=1000, replace=True)`

Comment: Or maybe you don't want to use `replace=True`?

Comment: no I need unique rows without replacement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't want duplicates (i.e. to use `replace=True`), go with a custom [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html):

```
out = (df.groupby('class', group_keys=False)
         .apply(lambda g: g.sample(n=min(1000, len(g))))
      )
```

Or shuffle the whole DataFrame and use [`groupby.head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.head.html):

```
out = df.sample(frac=1).groupby('class').head(1000)
```

Output:

```
         Date  class  other_col1  other_col2
2  2023-10-22      1           3          72
1  2023-10-21      1           6          10
3  2023-10-23      2           1           6
4  2023-10-24      3           4           8
0  2023-10-20      4           5          15
```

Comment: Thank you, your approach definitely better than mine, and 2nd has useful property - shuffling

Comment: I'd go for the second approach, it's faster and cleaner.